# Выборка из таблицы поля с двумя значениями

Tags: php, mysql

Привет всем у меня стоит такая задача нужно реализовать фильтр товаров по характеристикам, запрос формируется вот к такой табличке

```
id---product_id---option_id---option_value
1 ---   1      --- 1 --- 10
2 ---   1      --- 2 --- 15
3 ---   2      --- 1 --- 20
4 ---   2      --- 2 --- 15
```

вопрос в том как построить запрос чтобы вытащить допустим только тот товар с весом 20 и размером 15

пусть option_id = 1 будет вес а option_id = 2 размер

помогите допиреть как построить запрос

я смог построить такой запрос в случае если выберется товар по задоному мной условию все работает как часы 
SELECT product_id FROM `products_rels` WHERE oprion_id in(3,1) and option_value in(15,10) group by 1 HAVING COUNT(*)=2

Но если поменять условия и скажем выбрать

SELECT product_id FROM `products_rels` WHERE oprion_id in(1) and option_value in(10) group by 1 HAVING COUNT(*)=2

результат выдает ноль строк на сделать запрос более универсальным?

Comment: Может

     select a.* from products_rel a join (select product_id
       from products_rel where option_id = 1 and option_value = 20) b
       on a.product_id = b.product_id
       where a.option_id = 2 and a.option_value = 15

Answer (score 1):

Из того что я понял попытаюсь составить запросы...

Выбирает все товары у которых вес 20 ИЛИ размер 15:

```
SELECT `product_id` FROM `products_rels` WHERE
(`option_id` = 1 AND `option_value` = 20)
OR
(`option_id` = 2 AND `option_value` = 15)
```

Выбирает все товары у которых вес 20 И размер 15:

```
SELECT `product_id` FROM `products_rels` WHERE
(`option_id` = 1 AND `option_value` = 20)
AND
(`option_id` = 2 AND `option_value` = 15)
```

Выбирает все товары у которых вес 20 И размер 15, группирует по `product_id`:

```
SELECT `product_id` FROM `products_rels` WHERE
(`option_id` = 1 AND `option_value` = 20)
AND
(`option_id` = 2 AND `option_value` = 15)
GROUP BY `product_id`
```

Comment: последние два запроса не рабочие...

Comment: Внимание, вопрос. Как они могут быть не рабочими?? Покажите код.

Answer (score 0):

читайте про sql конструкцию WHERE

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE item_weight = 20 and item_size = 15
```

Comment: и что это будет с таким запросом? посмотрите на конструкцию таблицы...